# I18n translations fnando

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm using I18n js library from https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js.
Where can I find basic translations for all the cultures (time, date, number formats?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sierrodc:

I think this could help you out. The translation are compatible with Ruby, but I think you can work with this as a start...

Here it goes:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale